# Printing a dedicated A4 format div with content as a pdf results in whitespace above the content on the second and third page, I wonder why?

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing

I am going a bit crazy here, I tried everything but for some reason my project where I simply want to print 3 pages a a PDF get broken whenever i go into the printing dialog.

Here is a direct link to the pages. Hitting cmd shift P opens the printing dialog where the problem appears.

https://outreach.geniusprompt.io/

I already tried to debug and see if any of the elements is causing this behavior. Doesn't seem like it. It seems it is a global problem. I really don't get what I am doing wrong here.
The code for the print media query is the following

```
@media print {
  body {
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
  }

  html, body {
    height: auto;    
  }

  .wrap {
    padding: 0;
  }

  .invoice-paper {
    page-break-after: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    box-shadow: initial;
  }

  .invoice-paper:last-child {
    page-break-after: auto;
  }

}
```

This is the html inside the body tag

```
  <div class="wrap">
    
    <div class="invoice-paper">
      <?php include 'components/header.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/first-tape.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/second-tape.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/third-tape.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/usps.php'; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="invoice-paper">
      <?php include 'components/icp-intro.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/icp-segment.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/quote.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/buyer-persona.php'; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="invoice-paper">
      <?php include 'components/quote-2.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/graph.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/quote-inverted.php'; ?>
      <?php include 'components/teaser.php'; ?>
    </div>

  </div>
```

[image]

[image: the third page when printed as pdf]

Comment: Could you make a simple example in HTML. We can’t see from what you’ve shown what is actually being produced as the final code. Using your browser devtools inspect facility should help with this. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I edited the question and added the link to the 3 pages! I hope somebody can help here

Comment: @KJ, that's way better than the Chrome PDF export. Which tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found out, the problem was the "gap: 4rem;" specification pushing the content down. I still got 4 pages with one being blank, but I guess that's a different problem.